# using QTimer for wake up application

Tags: qt, wakeup

I'm need to do some stuf at specific time. In Android I use AlarmManager to do this but in qt I don't know how to do it. With in my experience with qt, QTimer::singleShot stops when application closed, but I need to make it run after my application closed. I will run application on background but i really don't want to see my application on open application screen.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this for Android, or just general Qt?

Comment: general QT, I didn't mention this on question sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Task Scheduler API using QT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930846/task-scheduler-api-using-qt)

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking when I write that comment but this question for not Android, symbian with qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a class to handle this. The example below uses a "WindowManager" class, and a subclassed QMainWindow, but of course you could use any QWidget.

"wm.h"

```
#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow() {}

signals:
    void startTimer(int);

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
    {
        event->setAccepted(false);
        startTimer(5000);
        hide();
    }
};

class WindowManager : public QObject
{
public:
    WindowManager()
    {
        MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
        QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

        connect(w, SIGNAL(startTimer(int)), timer, SLOT(start(int)));
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), w, SLOT(show()));

        w->show();
    }
};
```

"main.cpp"

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "wm.h";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    WindowManager wm;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I can't try it now but I want to ask, if the application closed, timer won't stop right? and on timeout signal application wakes up?

Comment: The idea is that your main window can close (or dialog, or whatever it is), but the application will continue running in the background until the main window is shown again by the QTimer.

Comment: thanks for replies, I'm kind of new at qt, still learning I have one more question. if I use hide(), does application shown in open applications window?

Comment: @Utk12 See edits, again. :) It's a working example that I tested. You'll need to manually close it when you're done testing it (for example, with "Task Manager -> End Process" if using Windows), but you get the point. Yes, it does still appear in task manager. I'm not aware of another way to do it unless you use Windows API.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I will test it in a few hours :)